# Convert date to string format yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS - C#

Tags: c#, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [format date in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501460/format-date-in-c)

How do I convert a date into the following string format?

> 2011-07-25 15:45:00

Comment: Have you searched this site or MSDN?

Comment: @BoltClock - did not find anything that stood out.

Comment: The top answer tells you everything you need to know and has a bunch of useful links. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601160/custom-date-time-format, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717272/datetimeformat-issue/3717339#3717339.  Also **search** the site for: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+date+format

Comment: Do you mean "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" - or are you asking for the method call - if so that's pretty damn lazy!

Comment: Looks like you're pretty close to the right format string in your question title, +/- some capital/lowercase.

Comment: -1 for not knowing how to google

Comment: @James Gaunt - Not being lazy.  I wanted to verify.  So, do not be a jerk.

Comment: @Merlin - I did Google it and did not find a useful resource.  Figure I would ask since this has always been a helpful resource.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[here](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/) is a pretty good string formatting reference. for your question, you want something like this:

```
MyDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was not sure, just needed to verify

Comment: Be careful as "hh" gives you hours in 12h format, not 24.

Answer (score 3):

```
myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

should do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```