# Convert decimal hours to DD:HH:MM

Tags: c#, datetime

Im trying to convert a decmial number of hours to days, hours and minutes.

This is what I have so far, its not quite there yet. I need to subtract the number of hours from the days from the hours part if that makes sense?

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts from a decimal value to DD:HH:MM
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dHours">The total number of hours</param>
        /// <returns>DD:HH:MM string</returns>
        public static string ConvertFromDecimalToDDHHMM(decimal dHours)
        {
            try
            {
                decimal hours = Math.Floor(dHours); //take integral part
                decimal minutes = (dHours - hours) * 60.0M; //multiply fractional part with 60
                int D = (int)Math.Floor(dHours / 24);
                int H = (int)Math.Floor(hours);
                int M = (int)Math.Floor(minutes);
                //int S = (int)Math.Floor(seconds);   //add if you want seconds
                string timeFormat = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", D, H, M);

                return timeFormat;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts from a decimal value to DD:HH:MM
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dHours">The total number of hours</param>
    /// <returns>DD:HH:MM string</returns>
    public static string ConvertFromDecimalToDDHHMM(decimal dHours)
    {
        try
        {
            decimal hours = Math.Floor(dHours); //take integral part
            decimal minutes = (dHours - hours) * 60.0M; //multiply fractional part with 60
            int D = (int)Math.Floor(dHours / 24);
            int H = (int)Math.Floor(hours - (D * 24));
            int M = (int)Math.Floor(minutes);
            //int S = (int)Math.Floor(seconds);   //add if you want seconds
            string timeFormat = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", D, H, M);

            return timeFormat;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could use [`TimeSpan.FromHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromhours.aspx) to get the timespan, then you have all you need:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(Decimal.ToDouble(dHours));
```

For example:

```
int D = ts.Days;
int H = ts.Hours;
int M = ts.Minutes;
```

Comment: I wonder whether there are situations where the conversion from decimal to double could cause problems - it feels like there could be (and you might end up with one fewer minute than you expect, for example) but it's certainly a simple approach :)

Comment: I saw! Comment deleted :-). Nice answer (we all answered at the same time). You still got my +1.

Comment: You can get the desired string representation by using `ToString` like this: `ts.ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm")`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to subtract `(D * 24)` from hours... or you could just use:

```
int H = ((int) dHours) % 24;
```

If you're going to cast to `int` anyway, there's no need to call `Math.Floor`. So for example, you could actually use:

```
// I'd rename dHours as well, by the way...
int wholeHours = (int) dHours;
int days = wholeHours / 24;
int hours = wholeHours % 24;
int minutse = (int) ((dHours % 1M) * 60);
```

On the other hand, you need to be careful if it can be negative - all kinds of things could end up screwy in that case. If you don't believe you have to handle that, I'd explicitly check it and throw an exception if `dHours` is negative before you do anything else.

(Note that your try/catch block is pointless and distracting at the moment. Just get rid of it.)

Comment: thanks, it was the hours - (D*24) I was missing, works perfectly now

Comment: why is the try catch pointless? do you mean just for the code example I'm providing or in general?

Comment: @WraithNath: Any time you've got a single `catch` block whose body is just `throw`, you should remove the try/catch entirely. It serves no purpose (other than *arguably* for debugging) and clutters up your code base. Either way, if an exception is thrown within the body of the method, it will be propagated up the stack.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, I thought without the try catch block and without subscribing to AppDomain.UnhandledException then the program would just crash. Ill not bother in future if its not required! ( catching and throwing generic errors )

Comment: @WraithNath: Well you'll still get a failure if *nothing* catches the exception - but you were still rethrowing any exception you caught.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do something like this?

```
double d = 25.23523;
Timespan t = TimeSpan.FromHours(d);
```

This will give you:

```
t = 1.01:14:06.8280000
```

Then you can interrogate the `TimeSpan` object as you wish: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx

NOTE: `TimeSpan.FromHours` needs a `double` input, not a `decimal`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple.

```
double counter = 0.25;
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(counter);
textbox1.Text = span.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

result will be 00:00:15 seconds. If counter = 1, then the result will be 00:01:00 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

here is another post which expains it pretty good.

[Convert date to string format yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823291/convert-date-to-string-format-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-c-sharp)

MyDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

also

http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Comment: sorry i misunderstood your question, TimeSpan.FromHours(hours).ToString("dd:hh:mm"); is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetTimeString(Decimal dHours)
{
    DateTime dTime = new DateTime().AddHours(dHours);
    return dTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss");    // HH: 24h or hh: 12h
}
```